# Replace space between indicated phrases with underscore

Tags: python, regex

I've a text file where important phrases are indicated with special symbols. To be exact, they will start with `<highlight>` and end with `<\highlight>`.

For example,

```
"<highlight>machine learning<\highlight> is gaining more popularity, so do <highlight>block chain<\highlight>."
```

In this sentence, important phrases are segmented by `<highlight>` and `<\highlight>`.

I need to remove the `<highlight>` and `<\highlight>`, and replace the space connecting words surrounded by them with underscore. Namely, convert `"<highlight>machine learning<\highlight>"` to `"machine_learning"`. The whole sentence after processing will be `"machine_learning is gaining more popularity, so do block_chain"`.

Comment: I also find it great that you *need* something and that python provides all the necessary tools to get what you *need*. So, thanks for sharing this optimistic message with us. Do you have any questions?

Comment: So, how does it work?

Comment: Looks to be the same question posted under a different account yesterday: [How to convert all "<phrase>xx xxx </phrase>" in a file to "xx xx"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49087908) Maybe just everybody in the same class trying to cheat on their homework.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> text = "<highlight>machine learning<\\highlight> is gaining more popularity, so do <highlight>block chain<\\highlight>."
>>> re.sub(r"<highlight>(.*?)<\\highlight>", lambda x: x.group(1).replace(" ", "_"), text)
'machine_learning is gaining more popularity, so do block_chain.'
```

Answer (score -1):

There you go:

```
import re
txt = "<highlight>machine learning<\\highlight> is gaining more popularity, so do <highlight>block chain<\\highlight>."

words = re.findall('<highlight>(.*?)<\\\highlight', txt)
for w in words:
    txt = txt.replace(w, w.replace(' ', '_'))
txt = txt.replace('<highlight>', '')
txt = txt.replace('<\highlight>', '')
print(txt)
```